# CSS not linking/showing up?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having some annoying trouble with my code that probably has a simple solution but I'm stuck. My CSS APPEARS to not be linking to my html. I've scoured this website for a solution but none of the problems have been my problem.

- They're both in the same folder
- I believe my file names are all the same (where they need to link) but I could be wrong

My html: http://pastebin.com/shAF5kSd
My CSS: http://pastebin.com/qw6TUtjW

I'm the newest of the new to coding so please excuse me if this is a really stupid mistake in my code?? Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Just that it can't find maze.js which is fine since I haven't created it yet. Otherwise the css is in the list of sources.. @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your CSS.

`#map (` needs to be `#map {`

You can use a validator to check your CSS in the future and it will alert you of problems like this. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/